# **Failed to execute default Terminal Emulator.**

Tags: terminal, kali-linux

I've been seeing this error message "**Failed to execute default Terminal Emulator.**"
whenever I open the Terminal or PowerShell in Kali Linux (for about a week now) :

Until now, I haven't been able to find any solutions to this problem. I hope to receive an answer regarding this issue

Comment: That sounds like something in your Kali installation has been broken. I think it's time for a clean reinstall – unless you happen to know what happened. No big deal, Kali isn't meant for any persistent work anyways, but for [very specific, temporary pentesting problems only](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/). The way you phrased this question might be a slight indication that you have not yet come around to reading that part of Kali's documentation: *If you are looking for a Linux distribution to learn the basics of Linux and need a good starting point,*

Comment: *Kali Linux is not the ideal distribution for you. You may want to begin with Ubuntu, Mint, or Debian instead.*